# How to declare pair<int,int>::first

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to know if I can declare a pair [int, int] as a macro.

so i wonder if i can express it abstractly like

```
#define X pair<int,int>::first
#define Y pair<int,int>::second

int main()
{
    int a[10][10];
    pair<int,int> arr;
    int sum=0;
    ...
    for(auto p: arr)
        sum += a[Y][X] // a[p.second][p.first]
}
```

but it's wrong. can i declare a macro that i can express like that?

Comment: My first suggestion is to avoid macros as they do nothing but obfuscate readability. But to answer your question, how are you trying to use this macro in your code?

Comment: Here: `sum += a[Y][X]`, `X` should refer to the first element of a given `pair`. But which `pair`?

Comment: in `sum += a[Y][X]`, *to what* should `second` and `first` be applied?

Comment: Just curious, I guess.

Comment: I'm sorry for my scanty explanation. I will fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to define "pair[int,int]::first" like #define X pair[int,int]::first

Resist your temptation.

> ```
> /// Right
> sum += a[p.Y][p.X];
>
> /// Wrong
> sum += a[Y][X] //but i want to do this
> ```

Seems like you want to do this:

```
int Y = p.second;
int X = p.first;
```

With that, you can do:

```
sum += a[Y][X];
```

---

Even better, seems like a class would be more appropriate for you than a pair:

```
struct Coordinates { // choose an appropriate name
    int x;
    int y;
};
Coordinates c {1, 2};
int Y = p.y;  // not necessary, but just to get the exact syntax you want
int X = p.x;
sum += a[Y][X];
```

Comment: Thank you for a wise answer to a silly question. :)